# Reference for complex geometry factoid on degree of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Is there a standard reference for the assertion that if $L\to X$ is a complex, holomorphic line bundle over a smooth projective variety with negative degree then $H^0(X;L)=0$, i.e. there are no holomorphic sections of $L$?  The proof seems easy enough (although I'd like to know what generalizations there are) but I'd rather just be able to cite something than sketch the proof.

Comment: How do you define the degree of a line bundle? It's clear what it should be only for line bundles on curves.

Comment: By degree, I mean $\int_X c_1(L)\wedge \omega^{n-1}$ where $\omega$ is a Kahler form.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, Prop. 5.7.11 in Kobayashi's "Differential Geometry of Complex Vector Bundles" seems like a good reference.